# Which stream ciphers are supported in am335x cryptographic accelerator?

Tags: cryptography

I want to use cryptographic accelerator in aes cfb mode [or any other stream cipher]. According to http://e2e.ti.com/support/arm/sitara_arm/f/791/p/156983/658334 link cfb is supported in am335x. I used EVP_aec_256_cfb cipher in both command line and C program.  In command line it executed in default software implementation. In C program the context initialization could not be done. So is cfb mode or any other stream cipher supported in am335x crypto accelerator? Or any problem in cryptodev.ko module?

Answer (score 1):

After all researches I came to know that only CBC, ECB and CTR are supported in the latest linux versions. The driver for OMAP HW accelerator is built properly for CBC mode. In the case of CTR mode it should accept any length of data either for encryption or decryption. But in the case of hardware accelerator it expects data in the multiple of 16 for CTR mode also.

So one thing I can conclude is that the OMAP HW accelerator in am335x **properly** supports CBC mode only. Except for the data length issue mentioned above, CTR mode is also fine.